# Finding a String with the same hashcode() value as given String

Tags: java, hashcode

I'm trying to find a string that shares the same hash result as a given string.

For Example:

If I have the `String 'den'` and use Java's `hashcode()` method the hash result = `99,341`

```
String s = "den";
System.out.println(s.hashCode());
Result = 99,341
```

Knowing that the `hashcode()` method computes

> s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + 2[n-1]

How would I go about taking this result (**99,341**) and finding a string (**of the same length**) as `'den'` with the equivalent hash value?

Comment: Create a dictionary of String words and their associated hashcode.  You can't reverse the hash formula because you don't know the word length.

Comment: The word length is the same as the given String, so 3 in this case

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Homework exercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to solve this equation:

```
(x * 31^(3-1)) + (y * 31^(3-2)) + (z * 31^(3-3)) = 99341
```

It's a plane, every point in that plane is good for you as long as x,y,z are integers and between 0 and 255 (if you are only talking about ASCII).

One possible solution is `x=100, y=101, z=110`.
To **simply** find another one, you can just change the order of two of them and see what would be the third one, e.g.:

```
x=101
y=???
z=110

(101 * 31^(3-1)) + (y * 31^(3-2)) + (110 * 31^(3-3)) = 99341
```

where `y=70` (`F`) so `eFn` should have the same `hashCode` as `den` using the function in your question.